# Matching fields in SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm writing a query which will generate a report from a database, but I'm encountering the following issue. The report I'm generating pulls data from a table where the history of item prices is stored. The customer wants to add a column where the current price for that item is displayed, which would be the price with the newest effective date. However, I'm at a loss as to how to word that.

Paraphrasing, this is what I currently have

```
SELECT
  Items.Item_Name as "Name",
  Items.Item_Desc as "Description",
  Items.Item_Price as "Price",
  Items.Item_Date as "Date"
FROM
  Items
WHERE
  Date between '01/01/2017' AND '01/31/2017';
```

So far this returns all items which were changed during the month of January. However, I would like to add columns were the current pricing is shown, as well as a column stating when the current price is. Something like this:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Item  |  Description  |   Price   |   Date   |  CurPrice  |  CurDate  |
|--------|---------------|-----------|----------|------------|-----------|
|  Item1 |      Desc1    |  Price1.2 |  Date1.2 | Price1July | Date1July |
|  Item2 |      Desc2    |  Price2.1 |  Date2.1 | Price2July | Date2July |
|  Item1 |      Desc1    |  Price1.1 |  Date1.1 | Price1July | Date1July |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Basically, I should see all changes for every item, but the cell reflecting the current date/price for that item should be the same for any given instance of an item. How would I go about this? Thanks!

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question. I removed the database tags as it is unclear which one you are actually using. Please add the tag of *only* the database you are actually using

Comment: What database and product version you using?

Comment: What is your sample input and expected output?

Comment: Are there price entered in advance in table Item or can we assume that the record with the biggest date is the current price for a given Item?

Comment: I wrote the expected output in the thread. My current report generates the first four columns adequately. I need a way to generate the latter two columns. Version is SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0. EDIT: Records are entered in advance - the "biggest date" approach might not work in that sense.

Comment: Does date have hours? or they contain only the date?

Comment: The date does contain hours

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if SQL*Plus support subquery, but if it does, here is a possible solution.

```
SELECT  Items.Item_Name as "Name",
        Items.Item_Desc as "Description",
        Items.Item_Price as "Price",
        Items.Item_Date as "Date",
        (SELECT Item_Price 
         FROM ( SELECT Sub.Item_Price
                FROM Items AS Sub
                WHERE Items.Item_Name = Sub.Item_Name
                AND Sub.Item_Date <= GETDATE()
                ORDER BY Items.Item_Date DESC)
          WHERE ROWNUM = 1 ) AS CurrentPrice,
        (SELECT Item_Date 
         FROM ( SELECT Sub.Item_Date
                FROM Items AS Sub
                WHERE Items.Item_Name = Sub.Item_Name
                AND Sub.Item_Date <= GETDATE()
                ORDER BY Items.Item_Date DESC)
          WHERE ROWNUM = 1 ) AS CurrentDateEffectiveDate
FROM Items
WHERE [Date] between '01/01/2017' AND '01/31/2017';
```

We use subquery to obtains the latest price of an item.
Example : If there is no price for it today, it will use the price of yesterday.

Comment: Thanks for the answer AXMIM, but I'm getting an error because opening a parenthesis or placing the SELECT keyword causes an exception to be thrown, because the original query freaks out as it doesn't find the FROM keyword. I still voted you up because it's helpful, but it doesn't seem to work for this particular system.

Comment: @JackUnderhill This is mainly a syntaxe issue. I suspect `TOP` isn't a keyword in SQL*Plus. So I edited the answer to use the speudo column [ROWNUM](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns009.htm) instead. But there might still have a syntaxe issue elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You should use 
`ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [PARTITION_COL] ORDER BY [Order_Col] asc/desc) AS [Col_Name]`. 
In your case it would be

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT items.item_name              AS "Name", 
               items.item_desc              AS "Description", 
               items.item_price             AS "Price", 
               items.item_date              AS "Date", 
               Row_number() 
                 OVER( 
                   partition BY item_name 
                   ORDER BY item_date DESC) AS Num 
        FROM   items 
        WHERE  date BETWEEN '01/01/2017' AND '01/31/2017')t1 
WHERE  num = 1
```

Comment: Hi aFast, sql*plus doesn't allow me to use Row_Number() because it freaks out by not finding the FROM keyword. Still voted you up. Thank you for trying! :)

Comment: @JackUnderhill you know for a fact that it cant handle Row_Number() ? maybe we can figure it out? is the from claws the problem?

Comment: @JackUnderhill try `select t1.* ...`